# Static synchronized methods and non-synchronized static methods confusion

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a small confusion. Please have a look at the code below.

```
public class ThreadDemo {
  //non-static synchronized method
  synchronized void a(){
   actBusy();
  }

  //static synchronized method
  static synchronized void b(){
    actBusy();
  }

  //static method
  static void actBusy(){
    try{
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    final ThreadDemo x = new ThreadDemo();
    final ThreadDemo y = new ThreadDemo();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         int option = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
         switch (option){
           case 0: x.a();
             break;
           case 1: x.b();
             break;
           case 2: y.b();
             break;
           case 3: y.b();
             break;
         }
      }
    }   ;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

I know for sure that invocation of this sequence is possible.

```
x.a() //in Thread-1
y.b() //in Thread-2
```

Though still I have a small confusion that, we can easily see `x.a()` also calls `actBusy()` method
which is a 
static method. Method `b()` is a static synchronized method calling a non-synchronized
static method. When thread-2 gets a class level lock, the why call of `actBusy()` from Thread-1
is not blocked?

I am just logically confused, if a thread gets a class level lock, that class other
non-synchronized static methods remain open to be called from other methods (instance method). Why?

Comment: Small note, but it should be: `x.a()` and `ThreadDemo.b()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`actBusy()` is itself not synchronized but the callers methods are.

So Thread 1 does not block as it acquires lock on `this` object and no other thread holds lock on `this`, so it is able to call it without any problem.

That is because the `non-static synchronized` method locks on `this` the present instance and not on `class` object.

`x.a()` grabs a lock on the present instance i.e `x` and no other thread will be able to enter method `a()` of `x` until the present the present thread releases the lock.

Thread 1 --> `x.a()` `//acquires lock and holds it`

Thread 2 ---> `x.a() //blocks here until Thread 1 releases lock on x`

**EDIT:**

```
Class Object != Instance
```

So according to JMM they are different objects and two threads don't interfere with each other. So it allows you to call it.

**EDIT 2:**

> why does it allow calls to other static methods? Any logic behind it?

Suppose this:

```
public static synchronized int statefulMethod(){
    //this should be protected
}

public static int nonStatefulMethod(){
    //Just returns a static value such as 5
    //so this is thread safe as it does not have any state
}

public static synchronized int otherStatefulMethod(){
    //this should also be thread safe
}
```

So if thread 1 is in method `statefulMethod()` which is having some shared state to protect so it uses class level lock. Now thread 2 calls `nonStatefulMethod()` then it should not logically block as that method is thread safe and there is **no point in making that thread block here**.

Now if thread 3 calls the `otherStatefulMethod()` while thread 1 is holding class lock then thread 3 will have to wait as that method is also `static-synchornized`.

Comment: that thing i understand. I was actually looking for a logical explanation that static methods are class level methods, so once class level object has been locked, why does it allow calls to other static methods? Any logic behind it?

Comment: i totally understand that part. My point was see, static methods are class level methods not instance level. When b() was invoked, class level lock was gotten by thread-2. My only confusion is why java allows call to other static methods when class lock is already taken by some other threads. I know it does, but why? static methods are also class level methods.

Comment: @benz see example in my `EDIT 2`. And tell me if you get it now?

Comment: this makes perfect sense to me. Thankyou very much. Narendra, i have a stupid question, aren't static methods invoked using Class level object, as when statics are loaded, there is concept of 'this till that time'. Just a stupid query.

Comment: @benz There are no stupid queries :) I did not get the query though.

Comment: only last point, aren't static methods invoked using class level object?

Comment: No. only if the static method has `synchronized` with it, it will acquire class level object. There is no point in acquiring class level object unnecessarily. And `synchronized` keyword is the way of telling the JVM to acquire lock.

Comment: Thanks @Narendra, got the concept now. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

`static synchronized` method has a lock on the *class object*, while non static `synchronized` method has a lock on the *instance object* (`this`) - so both methods can be invoked concurrently, and one thread will run 1 while the other run the 2nd.

However, note that there is no [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) available in your code, because race condition requires a write, and such does not exist in these methods.

Answer (score 4):

> then why call of `actBusy()` from Thread-1 is not blocked?

Since your `actBusy` method is NOT synchronized. Even if you acquired class level lock you can invoke non-synchronzied static methods.

The point of marking the methods as `synchronized` is to enable locks. Only methods declared as synchronized are subjects to these locks. So if you acquired a lock (suppose class level lock) then any `non-synchronized` method acts as before and isn't aware of lock being acquired. This allows you to decide which methods need to be blocked and which don't.

Comment: thanks. That's where i am logically confused, static methods are class level methods, so once class level object has been locked, why does it allow calls to other static methods? Any logic behind it?

Comment: added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Lock objects are not hierarchical. Therefore obtaining a lock on the class itself does not supersede locks on instances of your class. They are separate lock objects and will only block code that attempts to lock on exactly that same object.

So if a thread enters a static synchronized method, the only threads that will be blocked are those also trying to enter a static synchronized method on the same class. Threads that are merely trying to enter an non-static synchronized method are unaffected - they are only competing against threads trying to enter non-static synchronized methods on that same object instance.

Regarding your comment below - only static methods marked `synchronized` are subject to the class level lock. If you want other static methods to be blocked, you must also mark them `synchronized`.

Why is this the case? Well, it would be rather presumptuous for the compiler to assume you need to lock *all* your static methods simply because one is marked as `synchronized`. It is assumed that the programmer knows which methods must be synchronized in order to ensure thread safety.

Comment: no this not my point of confusion. My point of confusion is, once a class level lock has been gotten by threads, why still call to other static methods are still allowed? I know its not allowed but i was thinking, why it is like that.

Comment: @benz See final paragraph above.

Comment: just a stupid question, aren't static methods invoked using class level object as there is no existance of 'this' uptil this time.?